# MVN Plugins downloading old versions of transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2
using in my pom. Its downloading internally codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar which is very old version.

maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1
downloading codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.4/plexus-utils-2.0.4.jar internally.

Even though I am making dependency management  plexus-utils-3.2.1 in POM.

Can someone guide to control transitive dependency to newer versions

I have tried

```
            <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>bin.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-io</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>bin.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

.....
.....
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
          <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
.....
```

How I can restrict maven to force download latest versions of transitive dependencies

Comment: Logs ` [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ Mtest ---[INFO]. https://*******/**/maven-internalfacing/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar ..... `

Comment: AFAIK, dependencyManagement does not work for plugins. But why worry? What problem did you experience?

Comment: Hi Thanks @JFMeier .. Maven plugins downloading old versions of dependencies. Ex: plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar .. plexus-utils-3.2.1 available already

Comment: Yes, but why is this a problem? Does something break? Do you need some other features? By the way: Then newest surefire plugin is `3.0.0-M3`.

Comment: Pls remove "maven-plugin" tag.